# Blank Order Confirmation Page with Invisible Order Data

Tags: cartthrob

Perhaps someone can help me find out why this is happening and how to fix it.

I have an add-on for EE 2.7.0 (CartThrob v 2.3.9) that we're using for orders. Once an order successfully goes through the payment gateway, it should show an order confirmation page (and has in the past). However, now it "appears" blank, because the source code shows that some styling is being added automatically to the body tag so that the opacity is zero (0)- rendering it invisible. If I change the styling in the "Inspect Element" mode of my browser so that I can see what is being hidden, I see all the correct order information and exactly what it should look like if it would only display. The order goes into EE just fine, sends out a confirmation email great.

This pseudo blank confirmation page happens whether I'm logged in as a Super Admin or not. When errors are turned on, there are no PHP errors or even notices. In my settings, "User Must Be Logged In" is set to "No". Session Expires in 18000 seconds. Clear Cart on Logout/Session is No. It does use Fingerprinting for sessions.

If I refresh the page, the invisible information is still there, so I don't think it's clearing the cart or the session at that point.

Any help or insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I very much doubt CT is doing anything to your body tag. I'd guess somthing in your css or js is doing that. Changed anything there lately?